# Parse ifconfig with Bash to get current IP address (wifi or ethernet)

Tags: macos, bash, awk, ifconfig

I'm trying to output my current IP address using a bash script. I'm trying to wrap my head around `awk` and managed the following:

```
/sbin/ifconfig $1 | grep "inet" | awk '$1 == "inet" {gsub(/\/.$/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

which outputs:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.178.57
```

I have two issues now: First of all, `127.0.0.1` is useless, how do I get rid of it?
Secondly, `192.168.178.57` is the IP address of my Wi-Fi connection. However I'd like the script to be able to grab the IP address of either Wi-Fi or Ethernet, whichever one I'm using at the moment.
A sample output from `/sbin/ifconfig` can be [found here.](https://gist.github.com/doque/23b67f284a4920984e99)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this awk script:

```
awk '/inet / && $2 != "127.0.0.1"{print $2}' <(ifconfig)
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get current used IP on a computer.

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'
192.168.1.30
```

OLD VERSION.  DO NOT USE!!!!!!

See my reply to this post:
[Linux bash script to extract IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336126/linux-bash-script-to-extract-ip-address)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm on OSX

Comment: @doque And there you do not have `ip route`?

Comment: It doesn't seem so: 
`~ » ip route
zsh: command not found: ip`

Comment: @doque If I do a seach of `ip route get` and `osx`, I get may post about it.  But I do not see any say that it does not work.

Comment: @Mehdi This is a very old post.  Se a better solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336126/linux-bash-script-to-extract-ip-address/21336679#21336679

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `ip` command instead of `ifconfig` as `ip` is the "future" and more reliable when compared to `ifconfig`.

```
$ ip addr show dev $(ip route ls|awk '/default/ {print $5}')|grep -Po 'inet \K(\d{1,3}\.?){4}'
10.251.26.9
```

Here this oneliner will which the default interface using the `ip route ls` command and gather the interface id and based on it the IP address of that interface will be grepped.

Here the `grep` command uses regex to get the IP address safely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing something and/or if you already have node, try [sindresorhus/internal-ip](https://github.com/sindresorhus/internal-ip)

```
$ npm install --global internal-ip
$ internal-ip
192.168.0.2
```

**Pro:** cross-platform

Note: I know it's not bash and that it doesn't use `ifconfig`, but I got here looking for a generic tool to use anywhere, perhaps it can help others.

Comment: You can also get your public ip with [public-ip-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/public-ip-cli)