# How can I determine the IP address from a bash script?

Tags: linux, windows, bash

How do I get the IPaddress of the current machine from Bash in a cross platform compatible way?  I need to get the IP address the same way for Windows Linux and Mac OS.

I am currently using `docker-compose` to create a local version of my full deployment, however I can't access it using localhost or 127.0.0.1, I have to refer to the current machines IP address, for example `curl 192.168.0.23:80`

Currently I make the user set the IP address manually:

```
# Return true if we pass in an IPv4 pattern.
not_ip() {
  rx='([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'

  if [[ $1 =~ ^$rx\.$rx\.$rx\.$rx$ ]]; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

# Ensure lower case
OPTION=$(echo $1 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])

case "$OPTION" in
"test")
    LOCAL_IP=${LOCAL_IP:-$2}

    if not_ip "$LOCAL_IP" ; then
      echo The test command couldn\'t resolve your computers Network IP. $LOCAL_IP
      echo
      help_comment
      exit 1
    fi
    python -m webbrowser "http://${LOCAL_IP}:80/" &
    ;;
esac
```

However I would love to be able to get this without having to have the user set any environment variables, especially when dealing with Windows machines.

Any ideas?

Comment: stop using botnet, intall gentoo.

Comment: Windows you can't directly use shell script

Comment: Which is your network interface from which you want to get the IP address ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux bash script to extract IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21336126/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect host before use of the following because of OS specific commands

**Windows (Cygwin command line )**

```
LOCAL_IP=${LOCAL_IP:-`ipconfig.exe | grep -im1 'IPv4 Address' | cut -d ':' -f2`}
```

**MacOS**

```
LOCAL_IP=${LOCAL_IP:-`ipconfig getifaddr en0`} #en0 for host and en1 for wireless
```

**Linux**

```
LOCAL_IP=${LOCAL_IP:-`ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'`}
```

Comment: I like this approach, the only downside is that docker itself creates quite a few virtual devices with their own IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  Unfortunately I will get back multiple address matches on every platform.  From experience the MacOS answer will probably work consistently, as long as I know which interface they are actually using.